# receiving a text file in udp in c

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to receive a text file over a UDP socket and then again save it as a text file. The code builds fine but when run, the output is a blank console and the text file is not created as well. After some research, I found out that I ought to give the number of bytes received to the `fwrite` function so I tried to use the `size_t` type, but it didn't help me :(.

Here is my code snippet:

```
char file_buffer[100];
while(1)
{
    // Tranmsit data to get file /
    server_length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if (sendto(sd, send_buffer, (int)strlen(send_buffer) + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr  *)&server, server_length) == -1)
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error transmitting data.\n");
        closesocket(sd);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(0);
    }
    size_t data=0;
    if(data=recvfrom(sd, file_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, &server_length)<0)
    {
        printf("Error receiving file.");
        exit(1);
    }        

    FILE *fp=NULL;
    fp = fopen("new_file.txt","w+");
    fwrite(file_buffer, 1, data, fp);
    {
        printf("Error writing file! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("File received:)\n");        
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone let me know what my mistake is.

Comment: You should really indent your code properly... Didn't you notice anything funny in the preview of your post, while writing it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

```
if(data=recvfrom(sd, file_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &server, &server_length)<0)
```

as `<` has a higher precedence than `=`. This means the `data` will be assigned either `1` or `0` depending on the result of the `<` test. Change to:

```
if((data = recvfrom(sd,
                    file_buffer,
                    BUFFER_SIZE,
                    0,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &server,
                    &server_length)) < 0)
```

Ensure the file was actually opened before continuing to use `fp`, check the result of `fwrite()` to determine status and query `errno` to determine failure reason:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("new_file.txt","w+");
if (fp)
{
    if (fwrite(file_buffer, 1, data, fp) != data)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("File received:)\n");
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```